# Coincident hypotenuses in the spiral of Theodorus

Tags: geometry, reference-request, triangles

In 1958, E. Teuffel proved that no two hypotenuses of the [spiral of Theodorus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_of_Theodorus) will ever coincide, regardless of how far the spiral is continued.  Apparently this was proved in "Eine Eigenschaft der Quadratwurzelschnecke", *Math.-Phys. Semesterber.* 6 (1958), pp. 148-152. I can't identify the journal, though my hunch is it's *Mathematische Semesterberichte*.  I haven't been able to track down a physical copy nor an electronic one through my institution.  Does anybody know a proof of this fact?

To phrase it formally, the $n$th triangle has hypotenuse $r_n = \sqrt{n+1}$ and origin-angle 
$$\theta_n = \arctan 1/r_{n-1} = \arcsin 1/r_n = \arccos(r_{n-1}/r_n).$$ 
Let $\Theta_n = \theta_1 + \theta_2 + \dotsb + \theta_n$. 
Then, the spiral's "corners" have polar coordinates $$(r_n, \Theta_n)$$ 
where $n \ge 0$. Two hypotenuses coincide iff $\Theta_n \equiv \Theta_m \pmod{2\pi}$ and $m \ne n$. Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe page 157 here? http://avalonlibrary.net/ebooks/Philip%20Davis%20-%20Spirals%20-%20From%20Theodorus%20to%20Chaos.pdf

Comment: The journal's title is actually *Mathematisch-Physikalische Semesterberichte*; [HathiTrust](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=pst.000052364303) has the volume (Band) you are interested in, but I do not have access to it.